# Similar phrases/words meaning "it is worth mentioning"

Tags: phrases, synonyms

What could be the other phrases/words with similar meaning of "it is worth mentioning"? e.g. I would like to start a sentence with exactly same meaning of

> It is worth mentioning that [......]

Comment: I think this question is too open-ended - there are far too many [discourse markers](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/discourse-markers-so-right-okay) with approximately the required function. It's probably a bad habit to include too much of this largely meaningless waffle/padding, whether you keep changing the phrasing or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Practically anything you put here might have "exactly the same meaning as" *It is worth mentioning that*, because the original phrase has so little meaning in the first place. If it has an actual meaning, it has very little to do with the literal meaning; it's more a hedge, apologizing for adding something which has only a tenuous connection with your main argument. You could try these:

> It may perhaps be observed without straying too far afield from our primary focus that . . .
>
> It is although distant from our current discourse not altogether irrelevant to adduce here the fact that . . .
>
> In light of what was written in 3.2.4 above anent the apparent inconsistency  between my current position and that articulated in Sartorius (1937), I may perhaps be forgiven for calling attention here to the fact that . . .

But by and large it may be taken for granted that if you mention a fact you consider it worth mentioning. You provide your reader no new information by laboring the point; you will do better to restrict yourself to a simple *Note that* or *Observe that*—or, even better, state frankly *why* the point is worth mentioning.

Comment: In order to improve brevity and to increase comprehension, sentences shall no longer be prefaced with the trite phrase "It is worth mentioning."

Answer (score 4):

**As a side note, ...**

**Another aspect of this is ...**

**Secondary to** [such and so] **is** [this other thing].

**There's an additional aspect of this:**

**There's more:**

**A related point to consider is ...**

Answer (score 3):

For the ultra-aspirational:

> "**It has not escaped our notice** that the specific pairing we have
>   postulated immediately suggests a possible copying mechanism for the
>   genetic material."

Answer (score 1):

A good word for this is [apropos](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apropos)--a loanword from French. It literally translates as "to the purpose." Apropos of your question, you could also preface your sentence with incidentally, but I digress.